# PHP echo without break

Tags: php, html, echo

I have the code below and it prints checkbox and a text below it. I want the text to be printed next to the checkbox on the same line:

`echo VmHtml::checkbox ('STsameAsBT', $this->cart->STsameAsBT,1,0,'id="STsameAsBTjs" data-dynamic-update=1') . vmText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_USER_FORM_ST_SAME_AS_BT');`

Comment: Since you are not using plain php features but some form of framework (class VmHtml) you should ask in their forum. Apart from that: layout in html is not done by the logic generating the html markup but by styling (css style sheets) that are coded separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently you are using virtuemart, which is a commerce extension for Joomla.  Like many advanced extensions, it is quite complicated, and has an entire subsystem of code.

For example, Virtuemart has its own template system which can be used to change the look of the virtuemart pages within the system.

Templates have their own style sheets which can be used to style the individual elements.

At the end of the day your code is simply outputting html, and the html is being styled by the css and javascript that is included on the page.

You'll need to inspect the html and css and determine why you are not getting the behavior you want, and modify that css within the appropriate css file that is part of the virtuemart template.

In summary, you are looking in the wrong place.  The php code is going to output the html markup, and you are not going to fix style issues in the php code but rather in the css file(s) which style that markup.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I had to do some modification in CSS file of Virtuemart. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use code below I think. I tried and it works fine in both chrome and firefox, you should set it to print out like this.

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1">
  Lorem ipsum sed aliquam
</label>
```

Even:

```
<label>Lorem ipsum sed aliquam</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1">
```

Answer (score -1):

Inspect that text on the webpage in browser(the easiest to do it in chrome), take a look at the element size and it's parent elements. The reason is probably because text is too long to fit parent element.
The fastest solution make text size a bit smaller so it fit.

Comment: This is the code when its inspected:

 '<div class="output-shipto">
   <input type="hidden" name="STsameAsBT" value="0"><input id="STsameAsBTjs" data-dynamic-update="1" type="checkbox" name="STsameAsBT" value="1" checked="checked">Use for the shipto same as billto address   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>'

its one div with two inputs but I couldn't know how to fix it